Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56
I'm working on a flutter project, I'm trying to build the application for the iOS but I keep getting this error
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibilityPacks'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCompatibility56'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObservation'
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'Symbols'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_FirebaseAnalytics in FirebaseAnalytics(Analytics+StoreKit.o)
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_FirebaseAnalytics in FirebaseAnalytics(Analytics+SwiftUI.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56_$_FirebaseAnalytics)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

has anyone faced the same problem while building the iOS app and if please someone can help me solve this.
I tried to change the version of the iOS for the build I looked for the libraries and framework in Xcode but I didn't find anything I'm using code 14.2 and I can't update it anymore.

Did you find some solution, i have the exat same issue. Also locked on 14.2.

I changed my dart sdk to 3.3.0 and now it works

same, solve the issue by update the xcode version, shout out omarzl
link
omarzl commented on Jun 29, 2023
"Oh I see that Xcode 14.2 doesn't have the static lib libswiftCompatibility56.a while Xcode 14.3 has it.
You should be able to solve your issue by upgrading to 14.3 without any additional linker flags."

Add this other linker flag from the link below:
-L$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME)
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11960#issuecomment-1610361087

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

it doesn't work. And even on your link people say that it doesn't work too

Yes, indeed. it is not root cause solving and for workaround patch.
The root cause of this issue came from old runtime with new build package.
We have to run with new build environment.
